# Operate a given Java stream pairwise

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have given a `java.util.List`, e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and every element should be compared with its predecessor, using `Streams`:

```
1 - 5 = -4
2 - 1 = 1
3 - 2 = 1
...
```

I am searching for the right approach... Could I solve this the `reduce` method ?

Comment: You can solve it (start with trying). Though, this is not as such a `reduce` operation. Think of how would you write it without the `Stream`s and then try to move further.

Comment: what's the point of using a stream here, it's a simple for loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use stream, then I would suggest to use `IntStream` like this :

```
int size = list.size();
List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, size)
        .mapToObj(i -> list.get(i) - list.get(i == 0 ? size - 1 : i - 1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Outputs

```
[-4, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

---

But I recommend a simple loop in your situation.

```
int size = list.size();
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    result.add(list.get(i) - list.get(i == 0 ? size - 1 : i - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is another way of doing it

```
 ArrayList<Integer> collect = IntStream.range(0, integers.size())
                .collect(ArrayList::new,//supplier
                        (list, item) -> list.add(integers.get(item) - integers.get(item == 0 ? integers.size() - 1 : item - 1)),// accumulator this where the reduction happens
                        List::addAll); //combiner defines how the result from reduction should combine
        collect.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Streams as a concept are designed to abstract over the idea of a so-called sequential stream as well as a parallel stream.

As a consequence, various seemingly obvious concepts, such as 'what index are we on?' and 'what is the value of my neighbour element' just are not supported.

Your question doesn't make any sense unless you treat the stream as ordered. The Stream API does not like this, because implying an order wreaks havoc with the idea of doing the operation in a parallel fashion (having multiple CPUs each do a chunk of the work in parallel). For example, imagine that I have 2 CPUs and the stream op wants to smear out the job. It would give one CPU '1,5,2' and the other '1,3,2' and now this exercise becomes impossible to do.

As a consequence, this task is best done by clearly indicating that the job is sequential (only makes sense if you go from it from the beginning to the end, in that order), using language features that are designed for this: A plain old for loop. Streams are a hammer, and this task is a screw. You don't hammer screws in; you use a screwdriver.

If the purpose of this question is because you're attempting to get a job done, that's your answer: Don't use streams... and stop presupposing language features for any task, because perhaps said language feature is not a good fit for the task at hand.

However, it kind of sounds like this is NOT a 'get the job done' question, but an 'I may well know this is a bad fit but it is an academic exercise; I am trying to learn, and once I learned, this code will be deleted anyway'. In which case, well, if you try hard enough, you CAN put a screw into place using a hammer, after all. It just won't be pretty and will have all sorts of caveats.

The StreamEx library has the [pairMap](https://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#pairMap(java.util.function.BiFunction)) function that will get the job done fairly easily.

If you have an actual list, as you seem to here, I guess you can make an `IntStream.range(0, list.size())`, and then use `list.get()` inside your stream op to do it, too.

Comment: Thank you very much! And I totally agree with you, but -as you suggested- it is an academic exercise and I explicit have to use Streams to solve this one..